# Database commit performance

Tags: database, performance, hibernate, jpa

I develop an App and recently I've caught me on the thought. What of the following has better performance?

1. Perform single commit of 1000 entities.
2. Perform 20 commits with 50 entities at each commit.

And how do you think will it be implementation dependable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know is to test - you need to test with both options multiple times, with realistic data to find out which one will perform better.

In general, however, the expensive resources are

- Establishing database connections
- Transmitting data over the network

Since the amount of data is the same, you are simply creating multiple connections with the second option. This is likely to perform worse than your first option.

Comment: So you want to say it is impossible to perform commit to DB multiple times while single connection is established?

Comment: @MichaelZ - You can. I didn't read your question to mean you are using a single connection, but opening and closing connections in a loop. However, even though you _can_ reuse a connection, connections are normally pooled, so you can't be certain to be using the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Typically databases are geared towards set based operations, and the more you do in one go, the better your overall performance (i.e. my general guess would be that option 1 would be the quickest). There are limits of course, and different databases behave differently. For example, the more uncommitted work you have at any one time, the bigger your log file will have to be. You also need to weigh up the additional complexity of rolling back multiple batches if something goes wrong in the middle.

Since you're using hibernate, you can set the `batch-size` parameter to various different values to see what works best for you. I have been pretty lucky with a value of '20' in SQLite and a value of '100' in MySQL.